# getting relative height prop to work with window resize CSS

Tags: css

can anyone help me with this simple, supposedly easy, css task?  I'm trying to set a div height to resize with window.  This is what I have so far:

```
div.signIn {
margin: 20px 20px 10px 40px;
border-style: ridge;
border-color: #006a89;
min-height: 450px;
height: 90%;
width: 26%;
min-width: 255px;
padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
line-height: 210%;
float: left;
}
```

The width works fine, but not height.  There is no other style working on the div.  Can anyone spot why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `html` and `body` `height`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/tqnLB/)

```
html,
body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: it did something.  but now it goes off the window.

Comment: are there any elements in between `.popularIdeas` and `body`?

Comment: No.  oh interesting.  I changed body height to 90% and now it fits.  Thanks for your help